# Как сделать так, что бы url сайта начинался с www?

Tags: seo

В данный момент на сайт можно попасть только так - **something.ru**, а надо так - **www.something.ru**. Если попробовать открыть **www.something.ru**, написано, что сервер не найден.

Comment: Настройте DNS-сервер

Answer (score 4, accepted):

www - это лишь субдомен вашего сайта, вы также можете задать www1.something.ru. Сейчас www у вас не задан, поэтому сервер не будет найден.

Помните, что сайт желательно должен находиться на каком-то одном адресе, www.something.ru или something.ru - какой-то должен быть основным, какой-то вторичным. Со вторичного на основной должно стоять перенаправление (301), чтобы сайты поисковиками не воспринимались как разные. Таким образом, ссылочная популярность больше не будет распределяться между двумя доменами, а будет считаться общей, что позволит улучшить позиции сайта в поисковых системах.

Для подключения домена третьего уровня (www.something.ru) необходимо в настройки домена (DNS) вставить A запись www c указанием на IP сервера, где расположен сайт и внутри сервера добавить новый виртуальный хост для домена www.something.ru.

Можете также вместо A записи добавить CNAME (каноническое имя) запись, тогда будет плюс в том, что не нужно держать две записи с одинаковым IP, а просто будет как бы ссылка на уже существующую DNS запись. www CNAME www.something.ru

Answer (score 4):

У вас домен без `www`. Т.о. чтобы можно было заходить с `www` в настройку домена требуется добавить запись

`www.mydomain.com | CNAME | mydomain.com`

или

`www.mydomain.com | A | XX.XX.XX.XX`, где Х - IP адрес сервера.

Answer (score 1):

Как написали выше, Вам надо изменить настройки на стороне хостера.

Желательно что-бы сайт был доступен только с одного домена (как написал Firepro).
Что-бы это сделать, нужно потом в файле .htaccess прописать 301 редирект

Т.к. сайт доступен на something.ru, то желательно его и оставить:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.site\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://site.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Если принципиально с www, то:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^something\.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.something.ru/$1 [R=301,L]
```